Degeneracy of the Cassels-Tate pairing $\operatorname{Ш}(E/K)[n]\times \operatorname{Ш}(E/K)[n]\to \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Sha}{Ш}$ Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $K$. Let $\Sha (E/K)$ be the Tate-Shafarevich group, and let $n\ge 2$ be an integer. According to Theorem 15 in the 2022 lecture notes Selmer groups: Lectures at Baskerville by Christian Wuthrich, the Cassels-Tate pairing $\Sha (E/K)[n]\times \Sha (E/K)[n]\to \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ has kernel $n\Sha (E/K)$ on each side.
Could someone verify whether my understanding of this proposition is correct? (Especially in the context explained below).

When we define $\Sha (E/K)[n]_{\mathrm{div}}=\Sha (E/K)[n]\cap n\Sha (E/K)$, the induced pairing $\Sha (E/K)[n]/\Sha (E/K)[n]_{\mathrm{div}}\times \Sha (E/K)[n]/\Sha (E/K)[n]_{\mathrm{div}}\to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is non-degenerate without assuming the finiteness of the Tate-Shafarevich group.

Previously, I had thought that the pairing $\Sha (E/K)[n]\times \Sha (E/K)[n]\to \Bbb{Q}/\Bbb{Z}$ was non-degenerate, but upon reading Theorem 15, I now understand that this is not true in general. If my understanding is correct, the pairing
$$
\Sha (E/K)[n]/\Sha (E/K)[n]_{\mathrm{div}}\times \Sha (E/K)[n]/\Sha(E/K)[n]_{\mathrm{div}}\to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}
$$
is non-degenerate without any assumption on the finiteness of the Tate-Shafarevich group.

Essentially, yes. First the target group must be changed to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. Then I would not use the index "div" for your subgroup. Traditionally, this is used for the group of infinitely divisible elements. Note that your "div" group is actually $n, Ш [n^2]$. That is how this is presented usually and that is what I should have written in these lecture notes to be correct. (If an element in $Ш[n]$ is $n\xi$ for some $\xi\in Ш$ then $\xi \in Ш [n^2]$.)
